# Not Encrypting & Decrypting Properly

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

Something is funky with the following AES class I've written to do encryption and decryption. When I copy of the AES object and I choose to encrypt plain text, and then I immediately attempt to decrypt the text I just encrypted, it doesn't decrypt it fully (and does it differently every time).

e.g. I'm initializing it with a simple JSP like this:

```
<%@page import="com.myclass.util.AES"%>
<%
        String hexMessage = "0xe800a86d90d2074fbf339aa70b6d0f62f047db15ef04c86b488a1dda3c6c4f2f2bbb444a8c709bbb4c29c7ff1f1e"; 
        String keyText = "12345678abcdefgh";//*/

        AES e = new AES();
        //e.setKey(keyText);
        String plaintext = "This should decode & encode!";
        String ciphertext = e.encrypt(plaintext);
        out.println(ciphertext);
        out.println("<BR>");
        out.println(e.decrypt(ciphertext));    
%>
```

The output varies on each page load:
One time:

```
0x663D64E6A0AE455AB3D25D5AF2F77C72202627EBA068E6DEBE5F22C31
This should decoÁdìmèåV4ÉkÓ
```

Another:

```
0x5F5CF31961505F01EA9D5B7D7BFC656BD3117725D2EA041183F48
This s2??XêêÈ&ÀÜ§F?ÒDÒ­?
```

etc:

```
0xC7178A34C59F74E5D68F7CE5ED655B670A0B4E715101B4DDC2122460E8
Tà@¼R×ËÖ?_U?xÎÚ?Ba?b4r!©F
```

The class I created is below:

```
package com.myclass.util;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;    

   public class AES {
       private static String provider = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
       private static String providerkey = "AES";
       private static int size = 128;
       private SecretKeySpec key;
       private Cipher cipher;
       private byte[] ivBytes = new byte[size/8];
       private IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);


       public AES() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException{
           Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
           KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(providerkey);
           kgen.init(size); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
           SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
           byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
           key = new SecretKeySpec(raw, providerkey);
           cipher = Cipher.getInstance(provider);
           for(int x = 0; x < (size/8); x++)
               ivBytes[x] = 00;
           ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
       }

       public void setKey(String keyText){
           byte[] bText = new byte[size/8];
           bText = keyText.getBytes();
           key = new SecretKeySpec(bText, providerkey);
       }

       public void setIV(String ivText){
           setIV(ivText.getBytes());
       }

       public void setIV(byte[] ivByte){
           byte[] bText = new byte[size/8];
           bText = ivByte;
           ivBytes = bText;
           ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
       }

       public String encrypt(String message) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException{
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
           byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
           return byteArrayToHexString(encrypted);
       }
       public String decrypt(String hexCiphertext) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
           byte[] dec = hexStringToByteArray(hexCiphertext);
           byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(dec);
           return new String(decrypted);
       }

       private static String byteArrayToHexString( byte [] raw ) {
            String hex = "0x";
            String s = new String(raw);
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++){
                char[] t = s.substring(x, x + 1).toCharArray();
                hex += Integer.toHexString((int) t[0]).toUpperCase();
            }
            return hex;
       }

       private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
            Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("^0x");
            String s = replace.matcher(hex).replaceAll("");

            byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
              int index = i * 2;
              int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
              b[i] = (byte)v;
            }
            return b;
       }


   }
```

Based on the varied results, I'm wondering if something is getting messed up with the IV somehow, but I don't really understand why...

[EDIT] Looks like its not the IV, if I hard code that the decrypting still varies. If I hard code the key it stops varying, but still doesn't decrypt the text properly :-(.

--------------------- ===================== ---------------------

Adding the final solution I created below, based on owlstead's code and suggestions. It does the following:
1) Has a random key and iv on initialization.
2) Allows you to specify a key or iv as either a regular string, or as a hex encoded string.
3) Automatically truncates or null pads any given key or iv to make it the appropriate length.

NOTE: Item #3 could be viewed as extremely insecure since it allows you to do something stupid. For my purposes I need it, but please use with caution. If you null pad a short string for a key, your content is not going to be very secure.

--------------------- ===================== ---------------------

```
package com.myclass.util;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

   public class AES {
       private static Charset PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
       private static String CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
       private static String KEY_TYPE = "AES";
       private static int KEY_SIZE_BITS = 128;

       private SecretKey key;
       private Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
       private byte[] ivBytes = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BITS/8];

   public AES() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidParameterSpecException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException{
       KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_TYPE);
       kgen.init(KEY_SIZE_BITS); 
       key = kgen.generateKey();
       cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
       ivBytes = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
   }

   public String getIVAsHex(){
       return byteArrayToHexString(ivBytes);
   }

   public String getKeyAsHex(){
       return byteArrayToHexString(key.getEncoded());
   }

   public void setStringToKey(String keyText){
       setKey(keyText.getBytes());
   }

   public void setHexToKey(String hexKey){
       setKey(hexStringToByteArray(hexKey));
   }

   private void setKey(byte[] bArray){
       byte[] bText = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BITS/8];
       int end = Math.min(KEY_SIZE_BITS/8, bArray.length);
       System.arraycopy(bArray, 0, bText, 0, end);
       key = new SecretKeySpec(bText, KEY_TYPE);
   }

   public void setStringToIV(String ivText){
       setIV(ivText.getBytes());
   }

   public void setHexToIV(String hexIV){
       setIV(hexStringToByteArray(hexIV));
   }

   private void setIV(byte[] bArray){
       byte[] bText = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BITS/8];
       int end = Math.min(KEY_SIZE_BITS/8, bArray.length);
       System.arraycopy(bArray, 0, bText, 0, end);
       ivBytes = bText;
   }

    public String encrypt(String message) throws InvalidKeyException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING));
        return byteArrayToHexString(encrypted);
    }

    public String decrypt(String hexCiphertext)
            throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
        byte[] dec = hexStringToByteArray(hexCiphertext);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(dec);
        return new String(decrypted, PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING);
    }

    private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] raw) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 + raw.length * 2);
        sb.append("0x");
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", Integer.valueOf(raw[i] & 0xFF)));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

   private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
        Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("^0x");
        String s = replace.matcher(hex).replaceAll("");

        byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
          int index = i * 2;
          int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
          b[i] = (byte)v;
        }
        return b;
   }
```

}

Comment: Doug, could you try and clean up the question a bit, a lot of the formatting and text was lost. See the documentation of stackoverflow if you run into trouble. I'll take a look in the mean time.

Comment: As a java programmer, you need to get a better handle on object references. The setIV() method shows a lot of confusion.

Comment: owlstead, it looks like a friendly admin came and cleaned it up ;-).

Greg, If you've got any good resources in mind, I'm all ears.

Comment: You can use the [`Hex`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) in order to convert to/from hex.

Comment: [This answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/91629/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far#76344) recommends "Thinking in Java" and "Effective Java 2nd edition". Books are IMHO the best resources for such things.

Comment: I'll have to check those books out. Thanks owlstead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrote, with comments inline. Funny enough, the biggest mistake was generating the hexadecimals, so I rewrote that method. It's not perfect, but I kept to your original source as much as possible.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

/*
 * Add state handling! Don't allow same key/iv for encrypting different cipher text!
 */
public class AES {

    private static Charset PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); 
    private static String CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
    private static String KEY_TYPE = "AES";
    // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    private static int KEY_SIZE_BITS = 128;

    private Cipher cipher;
    private SecretKey key;
    private IvParameterSpec iv;

    static {
        // only needed if the platform does not contain CTR encryption by default
        if (Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null) {
            // only needed for some platforms I presume
            Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        }
    }

    public AES() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            NoSuchProviderException {
        // not much use without a getter
//      final KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_TYPE);
//      kgen.init(KEY_SIZE_BITS);
//      key = kgen.generateKey();
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
    }

    public void setKeyHex(String keyText) {

        byte[] bText = hexStringToByteArray(keyText);
        if (bText.length * Byte.SIZE != KEY_SIZE_BITS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Wrong key size, expecting " + KEY_SIZE_BITS / Byte.SIZE + " bytes in hex");
        }
        key = new SecretKeySpec(bText, KEY_TYPE);
    }

    public void setIVHex(String ivText) {
        byte[] bText = hexStringToByteArray(ivText);
        if (bText.length != cipher.getBlockSize()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Wrong IV size, expecting " + cipher.getBlockSize() + " bytes in hex");
        }
        iv = new IvParameterSpec(bText);
    }

    public String encrypt(String message) throws InvalidKeyException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING));
        return byteArrayToHexString(encrypted);
    }

    public String decrypt(String hexCiphertext)
            throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] dec = hexStringToByteArray(hexCiphertext);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(dec);
        return new String(decrypted, PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING);
    }

    private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] raw) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 + raw.length * 2);
        sb.append("0x");
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", Integer.valueOf(raw[i] & 0xFF)));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // better add some input validation
    private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
        Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("^0x");
        String s = replace.matcher(hex).replaceAll("");

        byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int index = i * 2;
            int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
            b[i] = (byte) v;
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String key = "0x000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F";
            String iv = "0x000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F";

            String text = "Owlsteads answer";
            AES aes = new AES();
            aes.setKeyHex(key);
            aes.setIVHex(iv);
            String cipherHex = aes.encrypt(text);
            System.out.println(cipherHex);
            String deciphered = aes.decrypt(cipherHex);
            System.out.println(deciphered);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Something is rotten in the state of Denmark", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // not always thrown even if decryption fails, add integrity check such as MAC
            throw new IllegalStateException("Decryption and/or decoding plain text message failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a different IV (NONCE) each time you use CTR encryption with the same key. Store the (random) IV in hex with the cipher text. If you want to generate a random key as you did before, create a method for that and let it return the hex string of the key. You could do the same thing for the IV. Currently it is unsafe to call encrypt() twice with different plain texts.

Comment: Man, I should have looked at the Hex generator! Thank-you for all your help!

Comment: Thanks on the note on making sure to use a different IV. I definitely understand how that is important. I was mostly worried about getting the basics working at first, but I will go back and add that stuff.

Comment: if that code worked for you, you may not need the bouncy castle provider: I used `!=` instead of `==` in the if statement

Comment: You are correct, apparently I don't need bouncycastle. I wonder what I was doing before that was kicking out those errors?

Comment: Probably the KeyGenerator that did not know how to handle `"AES/CTR/NoPadding"` or some such or other, or forgetting `"/NoPadding"` (default may be PKCS5Padding, and CTR does not use padding).

Answer (score 0):

Your byteArrayToHexString method is broken.  Integer.toHexString doesn't add padding zeroes but your code assumes it does.  The broken conversion to hex corrupts the encrypted string, and the conversion from hex back to a raw byte string corrupts it further.